# Controlling the cursor position in the typing animation using CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, effect, typing

So I have implemented to type out my name using CSS Animations. The idea is to have a typing effect with cursor staying at end of the sentence once it completes typing.

However, in my case, the cursor goes up to the end of the screen and waits there, and I don't want that.

I have referred this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/) to achieve the typing effect. As you can see in the tutorial, the cursor there stops after the sentence completes and does not run up to the end of screen.

My CSS snippet for the same:

```
.titles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  /*color: #7a9fd0;*/
  color: #595959;
}

.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: 2px; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 4s steps(30, end),
    blink-caret .75s /*step-end*/steps(50, end) infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@-webkit-keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@-webkit-keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange; }
}
```

Corresponding index.html snippet:

```
<div class="typewriter">
      <h1> Hi! I'm Abhijit Nathwani </h1>
    </div>
```

The page is hosted at http://abhijitnathwani.github.io

You can also check more source code at my GitHub Repo [here](https://github.com/abhijitnathwani/abhijitnathwani.github.io)

Comment: The width against your heading element is 100%, therefore the cursor goes to the end. If you would set width to `830px` as an example, the cursor would stop at the end of text

Comment: I tried that, it stops, and then jumps to the end of the screen. It does not help @Morpheus

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: Tried now and works as required! Thanks @user5014677

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 .typewriter h1{
   overflow: hidden;
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    animation: typing 1.3s steps(10, end), blink-caret .75s steps(50, end) infinite;
}

.typewriter {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

So it's obviously a problem with the width of the typewriter. To make it fit to the content I've set `display: inline-flex`. This make the whole div less smaller so I had to readjust the speed of the writer. It's still not perfect but I'll let you play with it to fit it correctly.

If you want to center the typewriter you can wrap it in another div and set it to `text-align: center`.

Comment: This works perfectly fine! Sorry I missed trying this. Thanks a lot @user5014677

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of tinkering in the inspector I finally found a way to do this.

You have to add this to the `h1`

```
display: inline
```

add this to the `.typewriter`

```
text-align: center
display: inline-block;
```

add a div around `.typewriter` with a class of `.center`

and add this to it

```
text-align: center;
```

I've made a pull request [here](https://github.com/abhijitnathwani/abhijitnathwani.github.io/pull/1) to your github project

The code looks like this:

```
.typewriter h1 {
   overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
   border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
   white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
   margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
   letter-spacing: 2px; /* Adjust as needed */
   animation: 
     typing 4s steps(30, end),
     blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

.typewriter {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

You wont have to readjust anything.

Comment: Added merged your pull request. But the changes you suggested, stop the typing animation. However, the cursor stays at the desired position. if you could check with the animation stopped, it would be great @yamboy1

Comment: Will look into it